# Using COALESCE()

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I found this interview question from [here](https://www.toptal.com/sql/interview-questions). Given these contents of the Customers table:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         Id          |     Name         |    ReferredBy    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |     John Doe     |      NULL        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |    Jane Smith    |      NULL        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          3          |    Anne Jenkins  |      2           |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          4          |    Eric Branford |      NULL        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          5          |    Pat Richards  |      1           |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          6          |    Alice Barnes  |      2           |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Here is a query written to return the list of customers not referred by Jane Smith:

```
SELECT Name FROM Customers WHERE ReferredBy <> 2;
```

What will be the result of the query? Why? What would be a better way to write it?
The answer as mentioned in the website is:

```
SELECT Name FROM Customers WHERE ISNULL(ReferredBy, 0) <> 2;
```

My question is how can we write the same query using `COALESCE()`, because as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) `COALESCE()` only returns the first `non-null` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the given case you can simply replace `isnull()` with `coalesce()` by replacing the function names.

`isnull(referredby, 0)` returns `0` if `referredby` is null else `referredby`. So does `coalesce(referredby, 0)` as if `referredby` is null, `0` is the first not null expression and if `referredby` is not null `referredby` is that first not null expression and is returned.

Actually the only difference between `isnull()` and `coalesce()` is that `isnull()` can take only two expressions where `coalesce()` takes two or more. Using `isnull()` you'd need to nest the calls if you had more than two expressions.

Comment: COALESCE() is also the standard way of saying this beyond SQL Server/T-SQL

Comment: @sticky bit, but the documentation says that the `coalesce()` returns only `non-null` values, in that case, does `coalesce(referredby, 0)` make any sense? Coz as per the example shown there `SELECT COALESCE(NULL, NULL, 'third_value', 'fourth_value');` returns only the `third_value` same will be the case with `coalesce(referredby, 0)` right? i.e it shows the `non-null` values of `referredby`, does putting `0` make it function like `ISNULL`, if yes can you please explain in detail how?

Comment: @merilstack: Sorry I don't get it. `COALESCE(NULL, NULL, 'third_value', 'fourth_value')` and `coalesce(referredby, 0)` are two entirely different things (function arguments). I don't understand what you want to show by comparing them.

Comment: @sticky, my understanding `COALESCE()` was just to find the non-null values, it was cleared [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#comparing-coalesce-and-isnull), thanks

Comment: @merilstack: Ah OK, interesting details I admittedly never thought about. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Good information about `COALESCE` and `ISNULL` is at SQL Server Pro [here](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/coalesce-vs-isnull) and MSDN Blogs [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/06/26/differences-between-isnull-and-coalesce.aspx).